# Any suggestions for dealing with XpsDocument GetFixedDocumentSequence performance issues?

Tags: wpf, xpsdocument

I'm trying to provide a live preview of XPS documents without hanging my UI thread.  Opening the document is fast enough, but when I call GetFixedDocumentSequence(), my UI becomes unresponsive for several seconds while the document chugs away.

```
// creating the doc is fine (0.005 seconds)
XpsDocument doc=new XpsDocument("BigFile.xps",FileAccess.Read);
// this hangs the UI for several seconds
FixedDocumentSequence seq=XpsDocument.GetFixedDocumentSequence();
// Once I have the sequence, GetPageAsync lets me pull out pages without breaking the UI
// ....
```

The obvious solution is to open the document on a worker thread, but the FixedDocumentSequence is tied to the thread that created it, so I can't access it from the UI thread, and if I try to call GetPageAsync from the worker thread I get an exception because DocumentPages contain visuals.

The only thing I can think of is to create the document on a seperate UI thread, break the  document into pages, and then save those pages as XPS files that the UI thread opens.  But that seems like a horribly complex solution.  Does anyone know if there is an alternative way to getting the DocumentPages that does not rely on the FixedDocumentSequence?

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple solution. It's called multi-threaded UI and it helps you to do everything as you would do, but have two UI threads instead of one. It means that your XPS can load on a seperate UI thread without any problem. I've implemented it myself in the past, and it's good.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dwayneneed/archive/2007/04/26/multithreaded-ui-hostvisual.aspx